# Linuxbrew from scratch without /usr/bin only with userhome/usr/bin

Tags: git, path, homebrew

I'm trying to install linuxbrew for normal users. I have minimally installed Oracle Linux 7.7 and put in a user test without root rights. I have gradually compiled and installed all packages that Linuxbrew needs under user test. Now the problem is under user test, all libraries and packages like git are in / home / test / usr / {bin, lib, lib64, include etc.} but brew doesn't know installed git or curl. Path in bashrc are correct so I think these are ENV:

[test@testing ~]$ which curl
~/usr/bin/curl

[test@testing ~]$ which git
~/usr/bin/git

[test@testing ~]$ env

```
    CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/test/usr/include
    XDG_SESSION_ID=24
    HOSTNAME=testing
    SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
    TERM=xterm
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    HISTSIZE=1000
    SSH_CLIENT=192.168.0.234 64558 22
    SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
    SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
    USER=test
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/test/usr/lib:/home/test/usr/lib64
    PATH=/home/test/localperl/bin:/home/test/usr/bin:/home/test/usr/libexec:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/test/.local/bin:/home/test/bin
    C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/test/usr/include
    PWD=/home/test
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
    HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/home/test
    LOGNAME=test
    SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.0.234 64558 192.168.0.200 22
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/test/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/home/test/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
    LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1001
    _=/usr/bin/env
```

[test@testing ~]$ cat .bashrc

if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then

```
    . /etc/bashrc
```

fi

```
    export PATH=$HOME/localperl/bin:$HOME/usr/bin:$HOME/usr/libexec:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/lib:$HOME/usr/lib64
    export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/usr/include
    export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/usr/lib/pkgconfig:$HOME/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

[test@testing ~]$ brew config

```
    HOMEBREW_VERSION: >=2.2.0 (shallow or no git repository)
    ORIGIN: (none)
    HEAD: (none)
    Last commit: never
    Core tap: N/A
    HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /home/test/usr
    HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /home/test/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
    HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /home/test/usr/Cellar
    HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
    HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 1
    CPU: single-core 64-bit sandybridge
    Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /home/test/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/bin/ruby
    Clang: N/A
    Git: N/A
    Curl: 7.29.0 => /usr/bin/curl
    Kernel: Linux 4.14.35-1902.3.2.el7uek.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7 (Maipo)
    Host glibc: 2.17
    /usr/bin/gcc: 4.8.5
    glibc: N/A
    gcc: N/A
    xorg: N/A
```

[test@testing ~]$ brew doctor

```
    Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
    with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
    working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

    Warning: Git could not be found in your PATH.
    Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae use Git
    checkouts instead of stable tarballs. You may want to install Git:
      brew install git
    Error: Git is unavailable
    Error: Failure while executing; `/home/test/usr/bin/brew tap homebrew/core` exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem for Git by moving the .linuxbrew/Homebrew directory to ~/usr, then:

```
    ln -s ~/usr/Homebrew/bin/brew ~/usr/bin
    eval $ (~/usr/bin/brew shellenv)
```

now brew knows where git is

```
    Git: 2.28.0 => /home/test/usr/bin/git
```

but he is still looking for curl under

```
    curl: 7.29.0 => /usr/bin/curl
```